# How can my text file get filled with ^M characters all of a sudden?

Tags: vim, osx, newlines

I have a text file on a Mac machine, and I've only ever used vi/vim to edit it. Today when I opened it using vi I noticed a bunch of `^M` characters everywhere. The only thing I did different today was redirecting an `echo "some text" >> file.txt` into it earlier, but I couldn't seem to reproduce this on a different file.

What made all these `^M` characters pop up all of a sudden?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36508/discussion-on-question-by-tan-wang-how-can-my-text-file-get-filled-with-m-chara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, since this is hypothetical, and the questioner doesn't think they did all of the following.

As mentioned in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266409/how-can-my-text-file-get-filled-with-m-characters-all-of-a-sudden?noredirect=1#comment461124_266409) by [Ralph Rönnquist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/148566/ralph-r%C3%B6nnquist), "Mac uses `^M` as line ending, Windows uses `^M^J` and Unix uses `^J`". Vim can deal with all three formats. For example, you can create a new file and specify which to use when saving, with (for example) `:set ff=mac`.

If you open a file with vim, it can automatically determine the encoding and display newlines appropriately. However, vim will only consider formats as specified in `fileformats`. Hence, if `fileformats=unix,dos`, then vim will never consider opening the file as a Mac format. So, if you created a file in Mac vim (i.e. with Mac newlines), then opened the file in Linux vim (i.e. with `fileformats=unix,dos`), then you'd see `^M` instead of newlines. Conceivably you may have processed the whole file on the Mac after creation.

Another point to consider if that you can have a file created in one format, then append to the file with `echo foo >> filename`. If the original format is Mac, and you append in Linux, then the file will contain a mix of formats. Assuming `fileformats` is set liberally (i.e. `fileformats=unix,dos,mac`, vim appears to select Mac format in this case.

Comment: `^M ` was the newline character for MacOS _Classic_, i.e. before 2001 (when MacOS _X_ became the default). MacOS X as a BSD-like system uses `^J`. If this was a (wrongly displayed) MacOS Classic file, the `^M` characters would be _instead of_ line breaks, not additionally.

Comment: @Dubu Thanks for that information. I didn't know that about Mac Classic. (FWIW I did already agree with the second point: `then you'd see ^M instead of newlines`.)

Comment: Oh right, I overlooked that, sorry.

Comment: @Dubu No worries. It's a relatively minor point. Your first point is good and possibly makes my entire answer invalid.